# How do I make a shell script open on double click without being prompted if I want to open it?

Tags: ubuntu

I've already set it chmod +x but when I click it prompts if I want to run it or read in text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each of the operating systems you list have different windowing systems, you'll need four different answers.  For Ubuntu, look at the preferences for Nautilus and select the option to `always execute file`.

Note: this is a global option and you incur some risk by changing it.